# Running same Ruby application in multiple environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm doing local development of a Ruby application, and want to setup both a production and development environment. I intend to use production locally almost like a staging server, to demonstrate the current state of the codebase to my client. However, I want to run an actual development environment with different settings for my personal use.

I intend to use virtual hosts to distinguish the two sites. No matter how I try to change settings in Apache + Passenger, they both run in the same environment though (either both production or both development). How can I make the same codebase run in different environments for different virtual hosts?

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/app.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.local
    ServerAlias app.example.com
    DocumentRoot /code/sites/app/public

    RailsEnv production
    RackEnv production

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug ssl:debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/app-dev.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.dev.local
    DocumentRoot /code/sites/app_dev/public

    RailsEnv development
    RackEnv development

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug ssl:debug

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app-dev.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/app-dev.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each app vhost a different PassengerAppGroupName so that Phusion Passenger treats them as different apps.

Comment: Amazing. Finally. I haven't seen this option referenced anywhere. How did you learn about it? I'm wondering if there is some Passenger reference I should be using instead.

Comment: I'm one of the Phusion Passenger authors. The option still needs to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much easier solution to your problem. https://ngrok.com/  It won't run as fast as it would if you set everything up, but it's infinitely easier to set up.

Comment: I may look at this, but it still doesn't solve the main issue, which is that I want the development environment for local use (caching classes disabled, etc. to make it developer-friendly), but also want things different for client presentation (assets pre-compiled, caching for speed, separate DB, etc.)

Comment: It can offer all of those things.  All it's providing is a secure way to tunnel out whatever port you open up locally to the internet.  Whatever you do locally is up to you.

Comment: Yea, but what I'm saying is that's the part of the whole setup that I haven't had a problem with; I'm doing router port forwarding and an Apache ServerAlias for the remote domain, and that part is working. What isn't working is regardless of the other setup parameters, I can't seem to make both instances run on different environments. Changing the external tunnel won't solve that on its own. Does anyone even know WHY it isn't working as is?